Questions on Thread Safety and Design Choices in C++20 Example
I'm working through an example from C++20 The Complete Guide by Nicolai M. Josuttis and have some questions about the code design and thread safety:
Closure by Value for tags: The example uses a closure that captures tags by value in threads that only read from it, not modify. What's the advantage of capturing by value here instead of by reference?
Thread Safety of std::cout.put().flush(): Is the combination of std::cout.put().flush() thread-safe in C++20, considering it's used inside a loop in a multithreaded context?
Lack of Synchronization: Given that std::cout.put().flush() is used without explicit synchronization mechanisms, are there any built-in guarantees for thread safety in this context?
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <thread>
#include <latch>
using namespace std::literals;  // for duration literals

void loopOver(char c) {
  // loop over printing the char c:
  for (int j = 0; j < c/2; ++j) {
    std::cout.put(c).flush();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::array tags{'.', '?', '8', '+', '-'};  // tags we have to perform a task for

  // initialize latch to react when all tasks are done:
  std::latch allDone{tags.size()};   // initialize countdown with number of tasks

  // start two threads dealing with every second tag:
  std::jthread t1{[tags, &allDone] {
                    for (unsigned i = 0; i < tags.size(); i += 2) {  // even indexes
                      loopOver(tags[i]);
                      // signal that the task is done:
                      allDone.count_down();  // atomically decrement counter of latch
                    }
                    //...
                  }};
  std::jthread t2{[tags, &allDone] {
                    for (unsigned i = 1; i < tags.size(); i += 2) {  // odd indexes
                      loopOver(tags[i]);
                      // signal that the task is done:
                      allDone.count_down();  // atomically decrement counter of latch
                    }
                    //...
                  }};
  //...
  // wait until all tasks are done:
  std::cout << "\nwaiting until all tasks are done\n";
  allDone.wait();                      // wait until counter of latch is zero
  std::cout << "\nall tasks done\n";   // note: threads might still run
  //...
}


Those are multiple questions and should be separated into multiple SO questions for answering. The part about cout is likely a duplicate of the various questions about cout thread-safety, e.g. here. To put it simply: The object itself has to handle it but the output might be interleaved. However, here you only write one character, so that cannot happen. And if the flush happens later, there is no visible effect either.

But if you learn C++20, you might as well use C++20's std::osyncstream

As for the capture by reference: The tags object is 4 bytes. A reference is almost certainly implemented as a pointer, which is 4 or 8 bytes. So you would only waste space and compute time in an added layer of indirection. For multithreading in general, copies are a bit safer since there is less risk of dangling pointers but that does not apply here since a) you already have another reference and b) the lifetime of the thread is constrained to that one function call.
